# union of every row in tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I really dont know what should be the title but i will try to explain it as clearly as possible.

I have an online food portal which includes various kinds of foods.Depending on the food , i characterize different attributes for different food.
For the sake of simplicity, assume that i sell cakes and wraps.Cakes can have the following attributes i.e they have weight and depending on the weights their prices vary.

Similarly,wraps can have two attributes , they can be large and small.

```
 base_product_table
        ID | product_code | product name | company_id 
        1  |  12345       | beer cake    |343434defee
        2  |  12346       | vodka cake   |343434deereee
        3  |  123451      | cheese wrap  |wqeqwewwe
        4  |  123453      | nb wrap      |weqwew
        5  |  123464      | ad wrap      | adwadw

 cake_table
           Product_code |Quantity | price | weight 
           12345        |  34     |345    |0.5 
           12345        |  343    |600    |1.0 
           12345        |  4      |845    |1.5 
           12346        |  341    |345    |0.5 

 wraps_table
           Product_code   |Quantity | price | size 
           123451         |  34     |345    |s 
           123451         |  343    |600    |l
           123453         |  4      |845    |s 
           123464         |  341    |345    |s
```

These are my three tables , one being base table while the other two can be joined with the base table to get the desired table.

The real problem with this method comes up when i have to display every product on my products page.I could have simply done `select * from base_product_table` but i need to display the product price with the product weight or size ,if present.

[image]
The above image shows what i meant by displaying products on the product page.

How can i achieve my solution ?

**Update:**
In cake table i have a cake but with three different weights then the output should be only one for that respective cake with weight being the smallest weight and the price of that smallest weight.

Similarly, wraps has two size Small and large , output will be only one for that wrap with the smaller record price.

Comment: Either join the base product table with a union of the other two tables, or join it with each of the other tables and create a union of those.

Comment: Could you please write an answer for it? i will appreciate it. @Barmar

Comment: I see the issue, you want to only show the product once, but you may have 1 or more prices, depending on the sizes available, correct?

Comment: For `product_code` 123451, do you want to have one record in the output with different column sets for the large and small sizes, or do you want two records?

Comment: @RobertoNavarro Yes exactly.

Comment: @BOTJr. Incomplete problem. share what output you need, product image is very abstract. do you need all products or some filter. Please share incomplete solution you have already tried.

Comment: @AcatnamedMidnight i want to display one product but the price has to the smaller one in case of wraps and for the cakes the price has ti be the record having lowest weight..

Comment: @GauravGupta let me update my question.

Comment: @GauravGupta does the update helps?

Comment: @BOTJr. Kinda helps. please check the answer if it helps.

Comment: @GauravGupta let me check it, i will notify you if any problem comes up.

Comment: @BOTJr. I suppose the question then becomes--what do you want to display? A weighted average price or a sum of the prices? Since you only want to show the product once, then you'd have to summarize the data in a logical fashion.

Comment: @RobertoNavarro see, i have updated my question.

Comment: @BOTJr., take a look at the first pass of a potential solution for this. Now, I primarily work in an Oracle DB, so you may need to retrofit the code for ANSI, but you get the gist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL returns the price for cakes, assuming you want the price for the smallest (in weight).

```
SELECT pt.product_name,
       pt.company_id,
       (SELECT MIN (price)
          FROM cake_table ct
         WHERE     ct.product_code = pt.product_code
               AND ct.weight = (SELECT MIN (sub.weight)
                                  FROM cake_table sub
                                 WHERE sub.product_code = ct.product_code))
           cake_price
  FROM base_product_table pt
```

If this works, than as previosly suggested, it's a matter of just joining the two tables:

```
( (SELECT pt.product_name,
          pt.company_id,
          (SELECT MIN (price)
             FROM cake_table ct
            WHERE     ct.product_code = pt.product_code
                  AND ct.weight = (SELECT MIN (sub.weight)
                                     FROM cake_table sub
                                    WHERE sub.product_code = ct.product_code))
              cake_price
     FROM base_product_table pt
    WHERE EXISTS
              (SELECT 'X'
                 FROM cake_table ck
                WHERE ck.product_code = pt.product_code))
 UNION ALL
 (SELECT pt.product_name,
         pt.company_id,
         (SELECT MIN (price)
            FROM wraps_table ct
           WHERE     ct.product_code = pt.product_code
                 AND ct.weight = (SELECT MIN (sub.weight)
                                    FROM wraps_table sub
                                   WHERE sub.product_code = ct.product_code))
             cake_price
    FROM base_product_table pt
   WHERE EXISTS
             (SELECT 'X'
                FROM wraps_table ck
               WHERE ck.product_code = pt.product_code)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i appreciate it

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? Also, does it return semi-expected results? I should add, the DB design is a bit odd, I would make a single products table, with the wraps/cakes etc as attributes to the item... you can then have an on-hand quantity table, which represents your counts and costing. Having a table per type is not so good DB design :(

Comment: Roberto what would be your design ? could you explain it a bit more ? i could use that design.I don't like this design either.I couldn't think of a more sophisticated design.

Comment: At a high level, drop the cake/wrap tables and add a column to your base_product_table... ie. product_type. Then create another table to store your product types for data integrity. See where I'm going? Then create a table where you store your onhand quantities, say, item_onhand, and each row on this table will have the product_code as the FK...

Comment: i understood till the point , adding a column but what do you mean by oh hand quantities? Could you pictorially represent it somewhere ? An example would suffice.

Comment: This is the closest I can find to what I'm trying to say: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBmpzGrNPPAhUK4WMKHVqUDSkQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdzone.com%2Farticles%2Fmongodb-design-of-product-catalog-documents-struct&psig=AFQjCNEe1OpjF4TrtgOqpKOC-UAwFyi6Rw&ust=1476295795896868

Answer (score 1):

I hope you need output like below query. Assuming both weight and size are same data type otherwise use cast to return same date type from both union results.

```
select product_name,price,weight as custom
from base_product_table bpt join cake_table ct on bpt.product_code = ct.product_code where weight = (select min(weight) from cake_table ct2 where ct.product_code = ct2.product_code)
union all
select product_name,price, size as custom
from base_product_table bp join wrap_table wt on bp.product_code = wt.product_code where size = (select min(size) from wrap_table w2 where wt.product_code = w2.product_code);
```

Comment: custom column for the sizes comes up empty? could it be they are of different types ?

Comment: It could be. please modify query and use casting to convert into common type. Other columns are populated correctly?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i appreciate it.Yes, i got a fair idea of how to do this.